# Getting error DirectApiRequestHasMoreThanOneAuthorization when calling logic app using HTTP trigger

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps

I have created a simple Logic app with HHT trigger response to take a test in JSON object and then pass it in teams channel. I have tested it successfully in Postman where I set Authorization type as "No Auth". When I am trying to call the same using powershell I am getting error
{"error":{"code":"DirectApiRequestHasMoreThanOneAuthorization","message":"The request has both SAS authentication scheme and 'None' authorization
scheme. Only one scheme should be used."}}
Below is the PowerShell code I am using . Please suggest what should I change in it.

```
$body ="{
      `"testName`": `"NewTest`"
      }"| ConvertTo-Json
$body  = $body | ConvertFrom-Json
$supportAreaUri = 'https://<URL>'
$supportAreaUri = [uri]::EscapeUriString($supportAreaUri)  
$Header = @{Authorization="None"}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $supportAreaUri  -ContentType application/json -Body $body -Headers $Header
```

Here is the screenshot of logic app
[image]

Answer (score 4):

When you created the logic app with "When a HTTP request is received" trigger, it will generate a url for request like `https://prod-04.eastasia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/830xxxxxxxxa5ebb/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=l5xxxxxxxxxxzMRM`. The url is protected with SAS token, the SAS token follows the base url in querystring. When you request in postman, it will fill the querystring in "**Params**" like below screenshot:
[image]

But when you request the url in powershell, you specify the header with `Authorization="None"`, the request method will assume that you don't use any authentication and it is conflict with SAS token. So it shows the error message `The request has both SAS authentication scheme and 'None' authorization scheme` which you provided.

To solve this problem, you just need to request the url without `-Header`.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $supportAreaUri  -ContentType application/json -Body $body
```

**By the way:** When you request the url without `-Header`, it may show this error message `You do not have permissions to perform action  'run' on scope '/triggers/manual/paths/'`. It was caused by the line `$supportAreaUri = [uri]::EscapeUriString($supportAreaUri)` . Actually, you do not need to do escapeUriString, so just remove this line and request again.